# memory leak check before close

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mfc

I have a relatively big MFC, MDI type application.I have fixed some memory leaks by Visual leak detector.Today I was looking on Task manager & the problem is when ever I open a file in the application , memory gets occupied ,but when I close the file ,the memory gets down only a little. So after some time of opening a file and closing ,it creates a large backlog of memory usage in task manager.

During debugging with visual leak detector , I have always debugged after closing the application,which in turn frees those memory before closing.I want to do some runtime memory leak detection, between two states of the application. (i.e before opening a file and after closing the file).

Please suggest a method of doing this.

Note: If any one needs more clarification ,feel free to ask.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx

Comment: I second Joachim Pileborg and if I remember correctly, you could tell visual leak detector to stop looking for leaks and start again to do so ( aka start leak detection directly before file open and stop it afterwards to get the exact thing you look for )

Comment: Thanks  @Joachim Pileborg .. will look into that.

Comment: This is one tool which you can give a try..   http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/

Comment: I would write a unit test (e.g., using [Google C++ Testing Framework](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/)) to reproduce the exact scenario you'd like to test and link in [AddressSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) to get [LeakSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/LeakSanitizer) to show you where the memory leaks are, if any.